# Angularjs error Error: Unknown provider: $sceProvider <- $sce <- $route <- ngViewDirective

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Below is my Angularjs routing code, but unfortunately i am getting error when i am running code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="routeApp">
<head>
<title>Routing - RouteParams</title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
</head>
<body>
<div ng-view></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="./vendor/angular/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.10/angular-route.js"></script>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var app = angular.module('routeApp',['ngRoute','ngSanitize']);
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/login',
        {
            templateUrl:'loginformroute.html',
            controller:'LoginController'
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/login' });
    //  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);

app.controller("LoginController", function($scope) {
   $scope.login = function () {
        alert(1);
   };
});


</script>
</html>
```

and i am getting below error

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`$sce` is included by default in `angular 1.2+`so you don't need sanitize anymore in order to get `$sce`. So use `angular 1.2` or further version and remove sanitize script. Hope it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Move your scripts in header tag

```
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="./vendor/angular/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.10/angular-route.js"></script>
</head>
```

> Also consider the **angular.route and angular version should be the same.** So use this version ( you can get it from [code.angularjs.org](https://github.com/angular/code.angularjs.org/tree/master/1.2.10)) instead of your version